# Activate uitableview by touch inside

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have disabled my tableview by

```
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

[self.tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];
```

I want to click anywhere in my table to reactivate the table .
can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as mentioned:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showTable:)];
[tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
```

and the action

```
-(void) showTable:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIView *table=recognizer.view;
        if ([table isKindOfClass: [UITableView class]]) {
            UITableView *tab=(UITableView *)table;
            if (![tab isScrollEnabled]) {
                [tab setScrollEnabled:YES];
                [tab setAllowsSelection:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Not tested)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (pretty easy, there are tutorials everywhere) or a `UIView` subclass (put on top of the table view) that removes itself from the view hierarchy as soon as you touch it (in `touchesBegan:withEvent:` or  `touchesEnded:withEvent:`).

Answer (score 1):

If your UITableView is full screen, then:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
    //make UITableView active here
}
```

If it isn't, you should do something like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(yourTableView.frame, touch)) {
        //make UITableView active here
    }
}
```

In order to do this, you have to make sure that self is the first responder, which you can do by including the

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

in your view controller and somewhere calling

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use UITapGestureRecognizer.